# Google Maps API - Miles Traveled in each State

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know if it is possible to get the miles traveled in each state instead of the total miles only.

For example [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Chicag+IL&destinations=Atlanta+GA&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=imperial](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Chicag%20IL&destinations=Atlanta%20GA&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=imperial) I would only get the total miles from Chicago, IL to Atlanta, GA but I want the total miles traveled in each state like in this example:

```
.IL=16 miles 
.IN=284 miles 
.KY=137 miles 
.TN=152 miles 
.GA=128 miles
```

Thank you for any help...

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you looking for miles to be traveled in driving directions by state?

Comment: Yes, for example [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Chicag+IL&destinations=Atlanta+GA&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=imperial] I would only get the total miles from Chicago, IL to Atlanta, GA but I want the total miles traveled in each state like in this example: 
.IL=16 miles 
.IN=284 miles 
.KY=137 miles 
.TN=152 miles.GA=128 miles

Comment: I will add this to the original question above also, Thanks for bringing up the question it does make alot more sence now.

Comment: when you click on the get directions it does say when you enter a state. example: Entering Tennessee, so one can just add up the miles from the top but how I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

There's no where in driving directions or in the distance matrix web service that breaks down stages by state.